# Parsing elements outside of divs to apply to arrays within Divs (Simple HTML Dom Parser)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am trying to learn Simple HTML Dom Parser, and as an introduction, I am trying to parse [ESPN's college football score webpage](http://scores.espn.go.com/ncf/scoreboard) and translate it into a plain HTML table.  I've been able to do everything so far except for importing the date.  The problem I'm having is that the data is structured like this:

```
<div class=gameDay-Container>
    <h4 class="games-date">Thursday, August 28 2014</h4>
    <div class=mod-ncf-scorebox> Containing games that I have scraped, which I want to add the date (Aug 28) to  </div>
    <h4 class="games-date">Friday, August 29 2014</h4>
    <div class=mod-ncf-scorebox> containing the next games that I will scrape, which I want the date (Aug 29) appended to </div>
</div>
```

The top section scrapes for the number of games within each date and places it into an array, and then the bottom section compiles the data for the table. (This is messy as I write it via trial and error; is there an easier way to do this?)

```
foreach($html_base->find('.gameDay-Container') as $dates) {
    $rows = $dates->find('.mod-ncf-scorebox');
    $count = count($rows);
    $supercount=$count.',';

    $megacount=explode(', ',$supercount);

    print_r($megacount);
}

foreach($html_base->find('.mod-ncf-scorebox') as $event) {
    $item['Date'] = ''; 
    $item['Away Team'] = $event->find('.team-name', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['Away Team'] = substr($item['Away Team'], 0, -1);
    $item['Away Score'] = $event->find('li.finalScore', 1);
    $item['Home Team'] = $event->find('.team-name', 1)->plaintext;
    $item['Home Team'] = substr($item['Home Team'], 0, -1);
    $item['Home Score'] = $event->find('li.finalScore', 2)->plaintext;
    $item['Game Status'] = $event->find('div.game-status', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['Game ID'] = $event->find('p', 0)->id;
    $item['Game ID'] = substr($item['Game ID'], 0, strpos( $item['Game ID'], '-'));
    $item['Week'] = $week;
    $item['League'] = 'NCAA Football';

    $NCAAFscores[] = $item;
}
```

**The question**:  can I get the date of the game to be added to each line within the table? If I have to use the array setup, can I take the values from it and do some sort of count?  Is there an easier way that I'm just completely overlooking?

**The answer**:

Per Enissay's suggestion below, I nested the foreach statements, which worked out perfectly.  Here is the final snippet of code in case anyone out there has similar things.

```
foreach($html_base->find('.gameDay-Container') as $event2) {

    $date1 = $event2->prev_sibling()->plaintext; 
    $date2 = new DateTime($date1);
    $ymd = ($date2->format('Y-m-d'));


    foreach($event2->find('.mod-ncf-scorebox') as $event) {
        $item['Date']     = $ymd;
        $item['Away Team']     = $event->find('.team-name', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['Away Team'] = substr($item['Away Team'], 0, -1);
        $item['Away Score']     = $event->find('li.finalScore', 1);
        $item['Home Team']     = $event->find('.team-name', 1)->plaintext;
        $item['Home Team'] = substr($item['Home Team'], 0, -1);
        $item['Home Score']     = $event->find('li.finalScore', 2)->plaintext;
        $item['Game Status']    = $event->find('div.game-status', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['Game ID']    = $event->find('p', 0)->id;
        $item['Game ID'] = substr($item['Game ID'], 0, strpos( $item['Game ID'], '-'));
        $item['Week'] = $week;
        $item['League'] = 'NCAA Football';

        $NCAAFscores[] = $item;
```

}

}

Comment: I would say you could use [`strtotime()`](http://codepad.org/2faiwsfV), so something like `strtotime($event->find('.games-date', 0)->plaintext)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the way you proceed...

[image]

Follow this:

1. Games are grouped in `div` blocks/containers, each preceeded by the corresponding date, fetch these blocks ▶ `$html_base->find('.gameDay-Container')`
2. For each block, you can get the date ▶ `$block->prev_sibling()->plaintext;`
3. Then you find every game inside that block

   ▶ `foreach( $block->find('.mod-ncf-scorebox') as $game ) { ... }`

Not tested but it should work :)